# Fragment is running the webservice after each button click

Tags: android

I have an app that reads and display data from a weather API as show below.

[image: weather forecast]

Now those data you see in the RecyclerView are displayed via a Fragment. What happens is when I click the Forecast button in the toolbar the web service service is running again. Which means that the Fragment is added in the stack/click.

So here is my logic how to fix that. If the stack is null then add the Fragment. If not then don't.

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.forecast) {
            String tag = "forecastFragment";

            Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);

            if (f == null) {
                ForecastFragment forecastFragment = new ForecastFragment();

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.main_content, forecastFragment, "forecastfragment");
                ft.addToBackStack("added today current");
                forecastFragment.setArguments(b);
                fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                ft.commit();
            } else{
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_content);
            }
        }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Here is what I did, but still the web service is running every time I click the Forecast button.

Any ideas?

Here is my Webservice that is run by the ForecastFragment.

```
class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String FORECAST_KEY = "forecast";
public static String URL= 
"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
EditText editText;
public static String BASE_URL= "";
private String IMG_URL ="http://api.openweathermap.org/img/w/";
private String retrievedLat;
private String retrievedLog;

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
ImageView imageView;
public ArrayList<Model> modelList;
private Model m;

WeekForecastAdapter adapter;

public ForecastFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forecast, container, false);

    retrievedLat = getArguments().getString("lat");
    retrievedLog = getArguments().getString("log");

    //http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=35&lon=139&units=metric&cnt=10&mode=json&appid=d48708e1e4d8e2b60da14778acd8d56a
    BASE_URL = URL +"lat="+retrievedLat+"&lon="+retrievedLog+"&units=metric&cnt=10&mode=json&appid=d48708e1e4d8e2b60da14778acd8d56a";

    modelList = new ArrayList<>();



    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.week_forecast_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    adapter = new WeekForecastAdapter(getActivity(),modelList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if(savedInstanceState!=null){
        ArrayList<Model> items = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(FORECAST_KEY);
        modelList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(FORECAST_KEY);
        adapter.setModel(items);
    }else {
        if(isOnline()) {
            weekWeatherData();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    return rootView;
}
private void weekWeatherData() {
    modelList.clear();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            BASE_URL,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", response.toString());
                    try {

                        m = new Model();
                        JSONObject cityObject = response.getJSONObject("city");


                        String city = cityObject.getString("name");

                        String country = cityObject.getString("country");



                       JSONArray jsonObject = response.getJSONArray("list");


                       for(int i = 0;i<jsonObject.length();i++){
                           m = new Model();
                           m.setCity(city);
                           m.setCountry(country);
                           //list:
                           // {"dt":1464343200,"temp":{"day":23.05,"min":8.65,"max":24.96,"night":13.22,"eve":24.85,"morn":8.65},
                           // "pressure":950.2,"humidity":41,"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01d"
                           // }],
                           // "speed":1.16,"deg":342,"clouds":0}
                           JSONObject innerJSON = jsonObject.getJSONObject(i);

                           long dateTime = innerJSON.getLong("dt");

                           Date weekDay = new Date(dateTime * 1000L);

                           SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
                           String day = outFormat.format(weekDay);
                           SimpleDateFormat outFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");

                           String date = outFormat1.format(weekDay);


                           m.setDay(day);
                           m.setDate(date);
                           m.setDay(day);
                           //temp:{"day":26.92,"min":19.48,"max":26.92,"night":19.48,"eve":25.65,"morn":26.92}
                           JSONObject tempObject = innerJSON.getJSONObject("temp");

                           m.setTemperature(tempObject.getString("day"));
                           m.setMaxTemperature(tempObject.getString("max"));
                           m.setMinTemperature(tempObject.getString("min"));


                           double pressure = innerJSON.getDouble("pressure");
                           int humidity = innerJSON.getInt("humidity");

                           m.setPressure(String.valueOf(pressure));
                           m.setHumidity(String.valueOf(humidity));

                           JSONArray weather = innerJSON.getJSONArray("weather");

                           for(int j=0;j<weather.length();j++){
                               JSONObject weatherObject = weather.getJSONObject(j);

                               m.setDescription(weatherObject.getString("description"));
                               m.setImageIcon(IMG_URL+weatherObject.getString("icon"));
                           }

                           double speed = innerJSON.getDouble("speed");

                           m.setSpeed(String.valueOf(speed));

                           modelList.add(m);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.v("Theo","onSaveInstanceState called");
    outState.putParcelableArrayList(FORECAST_KEY,modelList);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.v("Theo","onDestroy called");

}
protected boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When are you starting your service??

Comment: Inside my ForecastFragment.

Comment: can you post the code for that part I wanna which lifecycle function of fragment is calling it ??

Comment: The webservice is run inside the onCreateView method of the Fragment.

Comment: The webservice is shown in my original question.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it's working or is there something else missing in my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
ft.replace(R.id.main_content, forecastFragment, "forecastfragment");
```

To:

```
ft.replace(R.id.main_content, forecastFragment, tag);
```

Because your `tag` (i.e. "forecastFragment") string value is different than the tag you are passing while adding the fragment (i.e.  "forecastfragment"). That's why it is not able to find the fragment by tag and adding it everytime on clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution too.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.forecast) {




         ForecastFragment forecastFragment = null;

            int backStackEntryCount =   
         getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (backStackEntryCount == 0 && forecastFragment == null) {
                forecastFragment = new ForecastFragment();

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                ft.replace(R.id.main_content, forecastFragment);

                ft.addToBackStack("added today current");
                forecastFragment.setArguments(b);
                //fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                ft.commit();
            }else{
                //getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_content);
            }
        }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```